# A question on cell division rates

Tags: cell-biology, development

It seems that in the adult human body the rate of cell division should be approximately equal to the rate of cell death, but how is this reconciled from the developmental phase where a single germ cell becomes the many trillions of cells in the human body. Is there some change in the rate of cell division throughout lifespan?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. This is not simply an answer site, but instead a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help. Consequently, **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site as are ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) questions **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details.

Comment: "Is there some change in the rate of cell division throughout lifespan?" Yes, there is. Is there something specific about this you want to know?